# Is there a way to connect an existing Hbase Table to Phoenix?

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I have a table in Hbase where There's a column in json, I want to retrieve the same data in Phoenix.

is there any comment ?

Comment: Please elaborate further.Question is unclear.Like whether you want just json data or some key-value mapped , etc.

Answer (score 0):

From the limited amount of information you have provided in your question, I believe you have an existing HBase table that was created and populated using HBase APIs and now you want to access that table using Phoenix without porting it as Phoenix table. Your problem can be solved by using Phoenix views on top of your HBase table.

Here is an example -

```
// Sample HBase table
create 'actor', {NAME=>'name'}
put 'actor', '1', 'name:actorName', '{firstname:"brad",lastname:"pitt"}'
put 'actor', '2', 'name:actorName', '{firstname:"tom",lastname:"hanks"}'

// Corresponding Phoenix view
CREATE VIEW "actor" ( actorId VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, "name"."actorName" VARCHAR) ;
```

Now you should be able to access HBase table data using Phoenix query.

One important point for you to note is HBase stores everything as bytes so its users responsibility to interpret the bytes appropriately so it doesn't matter whether you store json or any other format, its consuming applications responsibility to interpret and use it correctly.

Hope this helps.